# Как обратиться к массиву файлов в $_FILES

Tags: jquery, php, html, javascript

Есть у меня форма загружающая массив файлов строка загрузки выглядит вот так

```
<input name='file[]' type='file' multiple='true' />
```

Как мне обратиться к какому либо из файлов в загружеамом массиве на ум приходит только бред вроде

```
echo $_FILES['file[0]']['tmp_name'];
echo $_FILES['file[1]']['tmp_name'];
```

или

```
echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']['0'];
echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']['1'];
```

Comment: Второй вариант - кавычки не нужны для индексов. А вы вообще уверены, что есть к чему обращаться?

Comment: 100% есть в массиве 5 файлов мне просо выборочно надо их брать но я не знаю как = может их с начала в отдельный массив надо перевести для удобства..

Comment: Можно и [перепаковать в более привычный вид][1] массива.

   [1]:http://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.multiple.php#53240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такая структура

```
 echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][0]
               |      |      |
    имя поля  /       |       \индекс
         временное имя/
```

а вообще пользуйтесь print_r()

Comment: @eicto, порядок слегка не тот: 

    $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][0]

Comment: как-то не ожидал что там так по дурацки. давно видимо файлы не передавал

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте

```
    <pre>
    <?php
 print_r($_FILES)
 ?>
    </pre>
```

Вам станет сразу всё понятно. Там очень удобно все поля выведутся.

Answer (score 0):

если нужно загнать именна переменных в другие переменнные  можно воспользоваться

```
foreach($_FILES as $key => $value){ $string[] = $value; }
```

Comment: [занудаMODE=On]
Зачем использовать в foreach ключ, если он не используется?
Тогда уже foreach($_FILES as $value)